# Extend a generic class dynamically in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I need to extend on runtime a class with a generic signature.

For example, the class to be extended is:

```
public class A<T> {}
```

I need to get this dynamically:

```
public class B extends A<String> {}
```

I cannot use Proxy because I need to add the obtained class to the ClassLoader. I'm trying with javassist but I have no idea of how make it in the correct way.

Comment: What problem is it that you're really trying to solve?

Comment: @NilsH I'm devoloping a framework for Hadoop. Hadoop requires you extend a Mapper class defining some generic types. For my framework I cannot know the correct types before the running time, so I need a way to extend the class Mapper only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you know type only at runtime, then you will have to use casting. 
Like:

```
 class TokenCounterMapper 
    extends Mapper<Object, Object, Object, Object>{
     public void map(Object key, Object value, Context context){
    if (value instanceOf String){    
String castedString = (String)value;
        ...
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Avro to serialize my object during the communications. Avro can work automatically only if the classes are well defined.