# Extending class dynamically in java

Tags: java, android

I want to extend class dynamically in java for that I have found

[Extend a generic class dynamically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894571/extend-a-generic-class-dynamically-in-java),
http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/,
https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-subtyping-java

but that does not help me,

I want to achieve it like below

I have class A, Class B & class C

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
```

I want dynamically (at runtime)

```
class C extends A or class C extends B
```

is it possible, if yes then how,

Comment: probably there is much better way to achieve your task.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to do so with Classes. If you want to do so with interfaces, try [Dynamic Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)
Your mileage may vary on android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extend Java classes by Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886785/how-do-i-extend-java-classes-by-reflection)

Comment: What is the goal of this?